# Power requirements when overclocking a Pi to Turbo mode

Tags: raspbian, hardware, power-supply

Whenever I enable Turbo mode on my Pi and restart it, it fails to boot. I am currently using a normal 5.0V smartphone charger to power my Raspberry. I am assuming that it is not powerful enough...

So what are the power requirements for an over clocked Raspberry Pi?
And where can I find such power supply?

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this [forum post](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=57907).  Here's what a mod had to say (in response to the question):

> ```
> I'm currently using my HTC Wildfire S power adapter (TC E250 charger
> (5V/1A)), to power Raspberry - while it is working for basic setup,
> I'm afraid it may not be powerful enough while turbo over-clocking is
> enabled, resulting in SD card corruption (my raspberry stopped working
> "just like that" a week ago - SD card was corrupted, card itself is
> fine as far as I can tell - so I suspect the over-clocking was the
> reason). Question is - is there any power supply out there that will
> give raspberry enough juice even when it is over-clocked?
> ```
>
> I don't think the power supply is relevant. Overclocked or not, the
>   power consumption change is negligible, the actual SD card has much
>   more to do with it. If your tp1-tp2 voltage is near enough 5V, you can
>   almost rule out the supply (though there are some cases where you get
>   5v, but with a large ripple). I have some cards that run great with
>   the pi overclocked, while others refuse to boot properly. I am yet to
>   experience sd card corruption, but that's probably because of the
>   cards I use, not anything else.

Basically what it's saying is that your SD card is at fault, not your power supply (which you said was outputting 5V, and because it is a smartphone charger I am assuming that is at 1000 mA).

Answer (score 1):

The Pi and many other boards are a little too picky with their input voltage. Overclocking with 5V input is most likely insufficient. However, voltage protection circuits kick in at around 5.5V preventing much expermimentation.

You can try running your overclocked Pi from a bench powersupply at a little above 5V or alternatively you can find a recipe to modify a standard powersupply [here](http://www.iot-maker.nl/?p=615) (full disclosure, this is my own blog).

Answer (score 0):

A lot depends on your mobile's power supply. I used a low quality suply of a chinese tablet with 1500 mA but then my desktop speakers made sounds every time I plugged in the rpi o,o

Then I used my old mobile's power supply with just 500 mA and the raspberry runs rocksolid with a manual overclock of 940 MHz arm, 530 MHz sdram and 380 MHz gpu without overvoltage. As soon as I try to overvolt it doesn't boot because that would drain too much energy from the small power supply.

Sidenote: I only have a wifi-dongle and a small logitech wireless keyboard dongle in the USB-slots. If you use something like a n HDD it drains even more energy and you need a better power supply..

Answer (score 0):

I've been using the turbo preset on my RetroPie setup for a few weeks now without a problem, using two connections:

- When in the living room, I'm just using a standard HTC micro USB cable connected into my TV.
- When in any other room, I'm using a "Raspberry Pi PSU" mains plug that I got from cpc/farnell - http://cpc.farnell.com/raspberry-pi-psu/rpi-psu-uk-mk1/raspberry-pi-power-supply-5v-1a/dp/PW03060

I've not had any crashes or SD Card corruption, and I've been using it on and off for about 2-3 weeks now.

Answer (score -1):

Note my answer on power requirements [here](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/11718/8833). For overclocking with a rev. B, you will want to consider a supply of up to 1500mA. I don't see a list of power supplies anywhere, but you can check the specs of a power supply before buying.

[Here](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B0073FE1F0) is an example at Amazon that claims to provide 2.1A to each port -- this *should* work.